# PHP - mySQL query pass results as session variable not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have ran into a problem when passing a the result of SQL Query as a variable than as a session across all pages.

I currently have the "username" being passed as a session and that works but I have tried to set up a "privledge level" as a session exactly the same but this doesn't work while the "username" does.

I have tested the mySQL query on the database within phpmyadmin and it works fine, any help with this would be apprecated as I have been going round in circles.

```
SELECT privledge_lvl FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'
```

Result:

```
|privledge_lvl|
---------------
|2            |
```

Login.php

```
<?php
        require('db.php');
        session_start();
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){

                $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
                $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
                $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
                $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

        //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $privquery = "SELECT privledge_lvl FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'";
                $privresult = mysqli_query($con,$privquery) or die(mysqli_error());

        if($rows==1){

                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        $_SESSION['privledgelvl'] = $privresult;
                        header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
            }else{
                                echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
                                }
    }else{
?>
```

auth.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?>
```

index.php

```
<p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</p>
<p>Privledge Level <?php echo $_SESSION['privledgelvl']; ?></p>
```

Comment: you dont need the 2nd select, you get `privledge_lvl` in the first query by selecting *

Comment: **Please do not store plain text passwords** nor hash it with weak algorithms, use the [password functions](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) provided by PHP. Check: [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Comment: You never `fetch` a result.

Comment: @MehdiBounya thanks for the tip, I am pretty new to this as you can probably tell. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Check [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) too so you can prevent SQL injection attacks. Never concatenate user input to queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting a PHP warning from trying to convert a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object (the return value from a [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)) to a string on this line:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['privledgelvl']; ?>
```

You should be setting $_SESSION['privledgelvl'] using

```
$row = $privresult->fetch_assoc();
// or, procedurally, $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($privresult);
$_SESSION['privledgelvl'] = $row['privledgelvl'];
```

Or - as was pointed out - you can get it from the first query and not bother with the second:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
// or, procedurally, $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['privledgelvl'] = $row['privledgelvl'];
```

Comment: OP is using procedural, not OOP mysqli

Comment: @smith it doesn't matter the return value from mysqli_query is an object, so it can be used procedurally or OOP. But have added procedural calls in comments so OP can use either.

Comment: OP is obvious new to this, seeing -> is a little confusing. so thanks for the edit

Comment: Thanks for the help @Nick

Comment: Thanks for the help @smith